# convert yyyy-mm-dd to mmm-yy in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the way month and year is presented.

I have dataframe as below

```
Date
2020-01-31
2020-04-30
2021-05-05
```

and I want to convert it in the way like month and year.
The output that I am expecting is

```
Date
Jan-20
Apr-20
May-21
```

I tried to do it with datetime but it doesn't work.

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df['Date'),format='%mmm-%yy')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`.dt.strftime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to change the display format. `%b-%y` is the format string for `Mmm-YY`:

```py
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%b-%y')

#      Date
# 0  Jan-20
# 1  Apr-20
# 2  May-21
```

Or if `Date` is the index:

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).dt.strftime('%b-%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

date_sr = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series("2020-12-08"))
change_format = date_sr.dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
print(change_format)
```

Comment: Elaborate more your answer. It was flagged as low quality post.

Answer (score 0):

reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
%Y-%m-%d changed to ('%b-%y')

```
import datetime
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%b-%y'))
# reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
# %Y-%m-%d changed to ('%b-%y')
```